# How to add Authentication to single Controller?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a application with various controllers..I need to apply Authentication to only one controller while I am trying to add Authentication attribute, I am getting error because Its a parameterised constructor. Please help me anyone.

Comment: What error do you get? Show us your code.

Comment: Hi..I have filter class below like this. public AuthenticationFilterAttribute (IAuthorize authorizeRepository)..this is my constructor in the class. how to add to my controller this filter..Please help me

Comment: @ramnet add the full code for the filter to the question so that the community can get a better understanding of your problem and provide you with some help. you need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
[Authorize]
class Example : ApiController
{
 // class related stuff
}
```

Using the build in auth feature